# Will this usage of List<T> be a miracle or a mess

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list

I want to dispatch appointments to reps (I spare you the details).

I need to have, for each rep, a list of the appointments he cas do. I also need, for the second step, a list of the possible reps for each appointment.

I want to compile my data only once. What if I have something like this:

```
class Rep
{
    int repNumber;
    List<Appointment> availableApps;
}

class Appointment
{
    int appointmentNumber;
    List<Rep> availableReps;
}
```

Am I running after trouble? It seems fine to me, but I see it possibly creates a kind of infinite reference circle.

What do you think?
Thank you

Comment: I like the magnitude of your title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this. You see similar classes in the .NET Framework like forms and controls, for example:

```
myControl.childControl.Parent
```

myControl can refer to children controls, which can then refer back to it's parent.

Comment: That's true, I didn't see it this way! So what I want to do is already quite common in the framework.

Comment: Yes indeed. You just have to be careful not to infinitely follow these circular references in logic that consumes this graph. There are numerous algorithms for anti-circular-reference checking; the simplest, which works here, is a basic "last object" property which you set when you're about to follow a reference, and makes sure you don't traverse a back-reference that goes right back to the previous object.

Answer (score 5):

It's all fine; classes are reference types.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your typical many-to-many relationship.

Just make sure you have proper logic in there. If a rep gets fired, what happens to his appointments? Like all complex structures, there's lots of gotchyas that can trip you up.

Answer (score 2):

It's alright. Double-linked list has "infinite reference circle" too, so what. It's one way to design many-to-many relationships.

Keep that in mind if you ever want to serialize the data though. Some serializers don't handle this kind of stuff well. The same goes with custom implementations of `IEquatable` and overriding `GetHashCode`: there are ways to screw something up in these operations when your data structure is like that.

Basically, you're fine unless you want to implement some deep (rather than shallow) operations like cloning, comparing, serializing and so on. Then you have to be careful.

Comment: +1; good points! I wouldn't implement IEquatable if these reference types are mutable, though.

Comment: @TrueWill: well, yes, I wouldn't either, but you never know, I thought it's better to still point it out

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid; C# (and most other languages) handles types that reference each other in a circular manner. The reason it does not cause problems is that all variables of class type are references. So a `Rep` object wouldn't contain many `Appointment` objects; rather, it *references* a list which again contains *references* many `Appointment` objects. Each `Appointment` object references a list which contains references to many `Rep` objects (which might well be the same `Rep` objects that referenced the `Appointment` objects).